# Inkscape - Change SVG color using command line tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, image-manipulation, inkscape

Is it possible to change color of an SVG file to a single color, using inkscape on the command line?

For example, I have an [SVG document](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Pepsi_logo_2008.svg) with different colors like '#ffffff', '#004883', '#e32934'.

So with a command line tool is it possible to change this Pepsi logo to a single color file. I mean the the Pepsi logo should be completely in the red OR blue color.

If it's not possible with inkscape, is it possible with any other open source library (command line tool) for Linux? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be pretty easy with an XML parser in a programming language. I notice you've tagged your Q as 'ruby-on-rails' - that would be suitable. I think it could equally be done with PHP and SimpleXML, probably in about 20-30 line of code.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have done this and its working fine. But some time i came across some complicated SVGs, which has fill attribute inside path instead of style and so on... And i am not sure about what would be the format of a proper SVG.

That's why i thought instead of handling the unknown format, it would be fine if inkscape has some way to achieve this.

Comment: You might be able to write an Inkscape script to do this - I think they're written in Python. That should be launchable from the CLI. Not tried it myself, mind you.

Comment: @halfer - Have tried with sed command to replace the colors.
So far have seen 2 diff way of colors usage in svg files. 
**1. <path style="fill:#ffff00">
2. <path fill="#ffff00">**

so the following sed command should work for both the cases.

`sed -i -e's/\"#.\{6\}/\"#FF0000/g' -e 's/#.*;/#FF0000;/g' pepsi.svg`

Plz let me know if anything better can be done...

Comment: It might work, but I wouldn't do it - what happens if another non-colour related parameter takes a matching argument? XML is best processed as XML; as I say, I'd just use an XML parser. If you want to give that a go, make a start, post up some code, and someone will assist `:)`